# Chronicle queue bookmarking

Tags: multithreading, chronicle

I have a situation where I need to get the end index of the queue in one thread, then resume reading it from another thread at some later point in time.

If it were the same thread, this would be trivial. I'd just create a tailer, move to end, and then start reading from that tailer when I'm ready.

The documentation states that using a tailer from multiple threads will result in undefined behavior. I presume that creating a Tailer in one thread with .createTailer().direction(FORWARD).toEnd(), and then reading from that Tailer in another thread would violate the contract. If not, let me know, because that would be the easiest solution.

What I've tried to do instead is:

```
bookmarkTailer = queue.createTailer().direction(FORWARD).toEnd();
bookmarkIndex = bookmarkTailer.index(); //Left open to ensure file doesn't expire

doAsync(()-> {
  tailer = queue.createTailer();
  if (!tailer.moveToIndex(index)) {
    //fail
  }
}
```

But the moveToIndex() call always fails.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest was to resume a tailer is to use a named tailer.

```
tailer = queue.createTailer("my-name");
```

You can create this again, at any time and it will continue from where it was up.